# Tomcat rejecting all POST requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I have created REST API in Spring which is returning value passed as JSON in body request plus some additional data. While running application using `spring-boot` everything works fine. I receives expected value every time i make request.

My target is to deploy this application on `Tomcat` on port `8080`. After deploying the app on `Tomcat` all `POST` request are rejected and i get following error:

`{
    "timestamp": "2019-07-11T12:33:41.877+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    "path": "/test/"
}`

The problem is I am making `POST` request using `POSTMAN`. This is how request body looks like:

`{
    "username":"somebody"
}`

Code of my API:

```java
@RestController
public class Test{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String token(@RequestBody RequestBodyData requestBody) {

    return "hello" + requestBody.getUsername();
    }

}
```

Why I am getting this error? Should I change Tomcat configuration or my code is bad?

**EDIT 1**
I have also deployed this app on `WildFly` server and everything works as I expected. I am using Postman correctly , the issue is either Tomcat or project configuration.

Comment: Make a POST request instead of a GET request as Postman does it.

Comment: I am making POST request in Postman

Comment: Tomcat tells you that you don't: '*"Request method 'GET' not supported"*'

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. I'm using POST, but Tomcat says that I'm using GET.

Comment: If the server says you are using GET then you *are* using GET. Learn how to use Postman.

Comment: Hello @JakeCooper you are making request to `/test/` make sure this endPoint has POST request and can you share the postman image in which you are making a request which gives correct result

Comment: @PatelRomil In the code above we can see the endpoint `/test/` has POST method. Its `/test/` because `test` is the name of application on `Tomcat`. This is how my `POSTMAN` request looks like: https://imgur.com/chDMfr6

Comment: Hello @JakeCooper change endpoint from / to /user/ and call from tomcat as /test/user/ and share the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change endpoint from `/` to `/user/` and ***`call from tomcat as /test/user/
( /appNameAsPerTomcat/user/ )`***

```
@RestController
public class Test{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String token(@RequestBody RequestBodyData requestBody) {

    return "hello" + requestBody.getUsername();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your request from *GET* to *POST*. This is evidenced by the error message you're getting back from your request:

```
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
"message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
```

Reading the error (usually) explains the error.